# Not able to use pool.apply_async()

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm just working around with the multiprocessing module of Python but ***the following code is running continuously but not giving any output***. What am I doing wrong? I have also tried `pool.close()` and `pool.join()` but with no effect.

Here's what I have tried so far:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
cpu_count = mp.cpu_count()
pool = mp.Pool(processes = cpu_count)

def func(val):
    print "\nInside Function.....\n"
    return val*val

results = []
num = 1
while cpu_count >= 1:
    results.append(pool.apply_async(func, (num,)))
    cpu_count = cpu_count - 1
    num = num + 1

output = [p.get() for p in results]
print output
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your code with

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ...
```

it's necessary if you working under windows due to multiprocessing implementation.

Following code prints [1, 4, 9, 16] as you expecting:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def func(val):
    print "\nInside Function.....\n"
    return val*val

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cpu_count = mp.cpu_count()
    pool = mp.Pool(processes = cpu_count)

    results = []
    num = 1
    while cpu_count >= 1:
        results.append(pool.apply_async(func, (num,)))
        cpu_count = cpu_count - 1
        num = num + 1

    output = [p.get() for p in results]
    print output

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Notice pool closing before program exit - just terminating program does not guarantee pool closing, it's processes can remain running.

Comment: Possibly it's your IDE's feature (i guess you are using IDLE) with stdout redirection. Script prints this message when i run it both from windows console and PyCharm.

Comment: Got it & Yes I'm using IDLE.